# Proper way of using Datepart() and group by in Kotlin

Tags: sql-server, kotlin

I am trying to view the data based on the current logged in user and group them together based on current month by using the group by() and datepart() method. However, it seems that my "" is incorrect. May I know what is the proper way of doing it? Thank you.

Below are my error and the codes:
E/Error: Invalid SQL statement or JDBC escape, terminating ''' not found.

```
 val sqlCon = SQLCon()
        val current = LocalDateTime.now()
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
        val formatted = current.format(formatter)      
val sql : String=
                   "SELECT Category,eAmount,eNote,eDate FROM Expenses where Username = '" + cUser + "'" +
                        "AND eMonth = DATEPART(MONTH,'" + formatted + ")'" +
                        "AND eYear = DATEPART(YEAR,'" +  formatted + ")'"
                statement = connection!!.createStatement()
                var rs : ResultSet = statement!!.executeQuery(sql)

                while (rs.next())
                {
                    var note : String = rs.getString("iNote") ?: ""
                    eList.add(ItemList(rs.getString("iCategory"), rs.getDouble("iAmount"),note,rs.getString("iDate")))
                }
                rs.close()
                statement!!.close()

                Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Comment: In your last "DATEPART(... " you forgot to closing ")"

Comment: ", DATEPART(year,'" +  formatted + "')" + "'"

-isint I have already closed it here ?

Comment: you are right, I was confused by the  + "'" at the end, Is ther one ' to many in your query? it's hard to read through all that string concatenation

Comment: perhaps you should debug and copy the content sql string variable into your sql management studio and execute the statement there to see where the syntax error is

Comment: I tried putting the string variable into SSMS, but it is without string concatenation. I am confused regarding the string concatenation now.

Comment: I just did a string replace with notepad++ to remove the " and + so now it looks like you have an error in the last two characters: DATEPART(YEAR,' formatted)'

Comment: You should think about using parameterized statements instead of concatenating you query. And the second thing would be, set a breakpoint and use your debugger the check the content of the sql variable so you see what your code put together. That makes it much easier to find typos like that